# Will destroying an enchantment attached to a permanent also destroy that permanent?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I play [Awaken the Ancient](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Awaken%20the%20Ancient) and enchant my mountain. My opponent plays [Priest of Iroas](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Priest%20of%20Iroas) and then activates its ability to destroy target enchantment and targets my Awaken the Ancient. Now I know that the enchantment will be destroyed, but does this destroy the mountain as my friend argues?

I was assuming not as it is only destroying an enchantment, and that when my mountain is enchanted with the card it only targets the enchantment not the card it is attached to, like if I had another card say, [Truefire Paladin](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Truefire%20Paladin) attached with [Shiv's Embrace](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Shiv%27s%20Embrace) and he used it do destroy the enchantment Shiv it will not destroy Truefire just Shiv's.

Comment: Why did your friend think that destroying the enchantment would also destroy the mountain?

Comment: Obviously not, I'd say?

Comment: I suspect that they thought it worked that way because if you destroy the permanent that the enchantment is attached to, the enchantment dies as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An effect does what it instructs you to do unless there's a rule that has you do something, and there isn't one here. If you destroy an enchantment, the enchantment is destroyed and your mountain is no longer a creature. Nothing states that the mountain would be destroyed as well.

Comment: Although this is correct, it could be confusing because though the card itself only does what is written on the card, game rules can cause side-effects, such as how destroying a permanent WILL also cause any enchantments on it to go to the graveyard.

Comment: Yeah, that first sentence was oh-so-wrong. (e.g. Moving an enchanted permanent causes the enchantment to detach and go to the graveyard.) Fixed it. Personally, I would drop that entire sentence.

Comment: I tried explaining this to him and he needed a confirmation for some reason. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

I am guessing that your friend's misconception is that the enchantment somehow "merges" with the mountain, since they now mentally identify it as a 7/7 creature, but this is an error. There is a card affected and a card doing the effect, and they are always separate in this case. The loss of the enchantment stops the mountain from being a 7/7, but that was an effect applied to the mountain; it was always a regular mountain underneath the transformation.